# Convert existing Xcode project to Framework

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

I want to convert an entire (huge) Xcode app project to a Framework - so that other apps would be able to use different part of the project. Would be easier than start dissembling the project (at the moment at least).
How can I do that?

Comment: Looking into doing this now myself. Internet doesn't seem to have much to go on. If I figure it out I'll let you know

Comment: @godmoney have you figure out how to do that? Please answer here.

Comment: @Lee Flaherty   Did you guys find anything related to the question